# Resolve `prop-types` in `.cache` after installing new plugin in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby and just following its tutorial. Whenever I install a new plugin, just say `gatsby-source-filesystem` or `typography` from the tutorial page, I cannot run `gatsby develop` again.

The error clearly say itself:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'prop-types' in '/Users/comp-name/hello-gatsby/.cache'
  resolve 'prop-types' in '/Users/comp-name/hello-gatsby/.cache'`

The only solution I can do is to remove `node_modules` and re-install everything again, then when I try to install another plugin. This loop happens and I find it quite annoying.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have [issues relating to gatsby's cache](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-cache-issues/), you can delete the `.cache` folder, or try the `gatsby clean` command which does the same thing.

However, a cursory google search reveals someone else has encountered a similar problem here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11375 which they resolved by updating to the latest version of `npm` and re-installing node packages.